# get single out parameter

Tags: c#

I have this C# function:

```
Fct( double [] x, out double a, out double b, out double c) 
{
    // ***
}
```

I proceed as follows to get the value of `a`:

```
double a , b, c;
Fct( myArray, out a, out b, out c)
```

How can I access `a` without having to define `b` and `c`?

Comment: You'll need to create an additional function that only has the one out parameter, unless you just want to just ignore b and c.

Comment: If you have control over the body of the function, you can use `Fct( myArray, out a, out a, out a)` and make sure you assign to the values in reverse order.

Comment: @empi - I'd even argue against "unfortunately"

Comment: @Wug Uh. How's that better than removing the unneeded parameters?

Comment: @WonkotheSane: I first wrote "you can't", but I needed more characters to add a comment :)

Comment: @J.Steen: you don't have to declare the function 3 times.  What if you want just a and b?  You can call `Fct(array, a, b, b);`, or you can write another overload.

Comment: @Wug Ah. With your explanation, it makes *more* sense. Still not pretty, but, yes. =)

Comment: @J.Steen: for the provided example with 3 arguments, maybe not, but if you had something with 4 or 6 or 15 optional arguments all those overloads would start to get messy.

Comment: @Wug If you had a method with 15 optional out arguments, I'd seriously consider telling you to make a class or struct or dictionary to return instead.

Comment: If I had a method with 15 optional arguments I'd seriously consider listening :D

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can overload "Fct". Add this:

```
Fct( double [] x, out double a) 
{
    double b,c;
    Fct(x, out a, out b, out c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to avoid the clutter you can make a helper function to "hide" the other variables:

```
Fct(double[] x, out double a)
{
    double b, c;
    Fct(x, out a, out b, out c);
}
```

The two doubles will still be created when calling this function, but it avoids cluttering up the context of the caller.

It's impossible to avoid the creation of the two doubles *somewhere* if you want to call `Fct`.  The entire idea of an `out` parameter is that the function doesn't have it's own value, it's referencing an external value, so that external value must exist somewhere.

Comment: Oh that "helper function" looks smart, although it does the same job. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is easy: You don't define your `Fct` function with all those `out` parameters if you don't want to guarantee that a value will be supplied for them.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no straight forward technique to solve the problem in C#. I believe you need to overload the function.

Also, according to the C# specification([C# 4.0 Specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/E/6/7E6A548C-9C20-4C80-B3B8-860FAF20887A/CSharp%204.0%20Specification.doc), section 21.1) - "A ref or out parameter cannot have a default-argument."